# Gtkmm - always same image when taking screenshot

Tags: c++, c++11, screenshot, gtk3, gtkmm

I have a small c++ (c++11) program that screenshots the whole screen and save it in a file when a button is clicked

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <gtkmm.h>
using namespace Gtk;

class MainWindow : public Window
{
public:
    MainWindow(): m_button("Take Screen Shot")
    {

        add(m_button);

        m_button.signal_clicked().connect(std::bind(&MainWindow::on_mouse_clicked, this));
        m_button.show();
    }

    virtual ~MainWindow() {};
protected:
    void on_mouse_clicked()
    {
        auto root = Gdk::Window::get_default_root_window();
        int height = root->get_height();
        int width = root->get_width();
        auto pixels = Gdk::Pixbuf::create(root, 0, 0, width, height);
        pixels->save("s.png", "png");
    }

    Button m_button;
};



int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    auto app = Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv);
    MainWindow mainapp;

    return app->run(mainapp);
}
```

The problem is: i get always the same image! the state of the screen when the app is launched. I want to get always the current state of the screen

Answer (score 0):

Got the same issue, but on few computers only. Don't know, why this happened, but seems to be gtk and/or display driver error (I've got this bug with Intel display driver).
Anywhere, the followin solution works to me, but only with native x11:

```
Display *dpy = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
Window rootWnd = DefaultRootWindow(dpy);

XWindowAttributes wa;
XGetWindowAttributes(dpy, rootWnd, &wa);

XImage *rootImg = XGetImage(dpy, rootWnd, 0, 0, wa.width, wa.height, AllPlanes, ZPixmap);
const unsigned long mRed = rootImg->red_mask,
    mBlue = rootImg->blue_mask,
    mGreen = rootImg->green_mask
;
for(int y = 0; y < wa.height; y++)
{
    for(int x = 0; x < wa.width; x++)
    {
        const unsigned long bgrPixel = XGetPixel(rootImg, x, y);
        const unsigned char blue = bgrPixel & mBlue,
            green = (bgrPixel & mGreen) >> 8,
            red = (bgrPixel & mRed) >> 16,
            alpha = bgrPixel >> 24
        ;
        const unsigned long rgbPixel = red | (green << 8) | (blue << 16) | (alpha << 24);
        XPutPixel(rootImg, x, y, rgbPixel);
    }
}
Glib::RefPtr<Gdk::Pixbuf> img = Gdk::Pixbuf::create_from_data(
    (guint8 *)rootImg->data,
    Gdk::Colorspace::COLORSPACE_RGB,
    rootImg->bits_per_pixel == 32,
    8,
    rootImg->width,
    rootImg->height,
    rootImg->bytes_per_line
);
img->save("s.png", "png");

XDestroyImage(rootImg);
XCloseDisplay(dpy);
```

P.S.: Please, do not forget that Xlib works with BGR, but Gdk::Pixbuf with RGB pattern.